# Generate 15 minute date intervals and join matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

What I would like to do is get the 15 minute intervals based on a date range in a row and insert them into another table.

Given the following code gets me the date range which is part of my goal:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(0,1), TIMEVALUE DATETIME, TIMEVALUE2 DATETIME);
DECLARE @start DATETIME2(7) = '2018-01-04 10:55:00'
DECLARE @end DATETIME2(7) = '2018-01-05 03:55:00'
SELECT  @start = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,@start) / 15 * 15, 0);

WITH CTE_DT AS 
(
    SELECT @start AS DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,15,DT) FROM CTE_DT
    WHERE DT< @end
)
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT DT, DATEADD(minute,14,dt) FROM CTE_DT
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

result:

```
ID  TIMEVALUE               TIMEVALUE2
0   2018-01-04 10:45:00.000 2018-01-04 10:59:00.000
1   2018-01-04 11:00:00.000 2018-01-04 11:14:00.000
2   2018-01-04 11:15:00.000 2018-01-04 11:29:00.000
3   2018-01-04 11:30:00.000 2018-01-04 11:44:00.000
4   2018-01-04 11:45:00.000 2018-01-04 11:59:00.000
5   2018-01-04 12:00:00.000 2018-01-04 12:14:00.000
6   2018-01-04 12:15:00.000 2018-01-04 12:29:00.000
7   2018-01-04 12:30:00.000 2018-01-04 12:44:00.000
8   2018-01-04 12:45:00.000 2018-01-04 12:59:00.000
..
..
```

What I want to accomplish is the apply the same logic above i from a record source.

So if my SourceData is

```
Col1    Col2    StartDate           EndDate
AA      AA      2018-01-01 13:25    2018-01-02 13:00
AA      BB      2018-01-02 13:25    2018-01-03 13:00
```

so with a query somehow use the start and endate to produce this result with just a query

```
Col1    Col2    TIMEVALUE       TIMEVALUE2
AA      AA  2018-01-01 13:15:00 2018-01-01 13:29:00
AA      AA  2018-01-01 13:30:00 2018-01-01 13:44:00
AA      AA  2018-01-01 13:45:00 2018-01-01 13:59:00
...
...
AA      AA  2018-01-02 12:30:00 2018-01-02 12:44:00
AA      AA  2018-01-02 12:45:00 2018-01-02 12:59:00
AA      AA  2018-01-02 13:00:00 2018-01-02 13:14:00
AA      BB  2018-01-02 13:15:00 2018-01-02 13:29:00
AA      BB  2018-01-02 13:30:00 2018-01-02 13:44:00
AA      BB  2018-01-02 13:45:00 2018-01-02 13:59:00
...
...
AA      BB  2018-01-03 12:30:00 2018-01-03 12:44:00
AA      BB  2018-01-03 12:45:00 2018-01-03 12:59:00
AA      BB  2018-01-03 13:00:00 2018-01-03 13:14:00
```

I would like to avoid using a cursor if I can. I have managed to make this work with a User Defined Function by passing the required columns with the select statement. I am hoping I can avoid using that if I can.

Comment: Tip: Using a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) avoids trying to fiddle with gaps in time, e.g. `IntervalStart <= SampleTime and SampleTime < DateAdd( minute, 15, IntervalStart )` using `<=` for the start time and `<` for the _subsequent_ start time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys

Answer (score 0):

Change the end of the first query so that instead of

```
SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

It says:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table1 d 
INNER JOIN SourceData sd 
ON NOT(d.timevalue2 < sd.startdate OR d.timevalue1 > sd.enddate)
```

Consider taking your first query that generates the dates, and just run it for now until year 2030 and insert the dates into an actual table. Keep the query hanging around so it can be used again in ~11 years to add some more rows to the calendar table

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a rCTE (which is a form of RBAR), I would use a virtual tally table to generate your dates:

```
--; is a statement terminator, not a "beginninator". It goes at the end, for the start.
WITH N AS(
    SELECT NULL AS N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
         CROSS JOIN N N4 --10000
    )
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,15*I,@Start)
FROM Tally
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,15*I,@Start) < @End;
```

If you want to generate 15 minute intervals for a combination of columns, you can then do a further `CROSS JOIN`. For example:

```
--Assume CTEs are already declared
SELECT V.Col1, V.Col2,
       DATEADD(MINUTE,15*T.I,@Start)
FROM Tally T
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES('AA','AA'),('AA','BB')) V(Col1, Col2) --This could be a CROSS APPLY to a DISTINCT, or similar is you wish
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,15*T.I,@Start) < @End;
```

Comment: I hit enter at the wrong spot as I was trying to figure how to use stackoverflow.  Was a bit of a pain in the beginning.  Thanks for the solution

Comment: @deswal ? Not sure what you mean there.

Comment: The "beginnator" (which made me laugh by the way) When I was originally posting this I didn't understand how the editor worked.  I probably just added a <br> at the wrong spot.